# Разница между типами var и object в c#

Tags: c#

Доброго времени суток!

Часто стал видеть в исходниках выражения типа

```
var a = конструктор или функция
```

Зачем используется `var` почему не используется определение конкретного типа объекта?

Да и в конце концов почему `var`, а не `object` если в шарпе любой объект унаследован от `object` ?

P.S. Складывается впечатление, что `var` уже используется и к месту и не к месту, наподобие некоторых ответов на форуме с использованием регулярных выражений, `linq`, и других страшных слов.

Comment: Var - это то же что и auto в с++11

Comment: @SoloMio: исторически, `var` возник раньше, так что скорее "`auto` это то же, что и `var`"

Comment: Сильное дополнение, @solomio при условии что я не знаю c++ :-)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Декларация

```
var x = new List<int>();
```

строго равнозначна декларации

```
List<int> x = new List<int>();
```

Просто компилятор дописывает за вас очевидный кусок, чтобы вам не пришлось писать одно и то же дважды.

Декларация же

```
object x = new List<int>();
```

— совершенно другой зверь! Если в предыдущем случае вы *могли* написать `x[0]`, то в этом случае такой код не откомпилируется, поскольку для `object`'а индексатор (да и все остальные функции, специфичные для `List<int>`, не определены).

У каждой переменной есть *статический тип*: тип, известный компилятору во время компиляции. Операции, который позволяет компилятор выполнить, зависят лишь от этого статического типа. Когда вы пишете `object x = new List<int>();`, статический тип переменной `x` — `object`, и вы не сможете у переменной `x` вызвать функции, специфические для `List<T>`. (Зато вы сможете позже присвоить переменной `x` значение, например, типа `string`: `x = "so what?";`.)

Объявление `var` означает «подставь само вместо `var` тип из правой части, <s>у меня лапки</s>». Поэтому при декларации `var x = new List<int>();` вы можете пользоваться методами класса `List<int>` для переменной `x`. (И, разумеется, вы не сможете присвоить переменной `x` значения посторонних типов.)

---

У `var` есть и другие преимущества перед явным объявлением типа, кроме сокращения записи. Дело в том, что вы можете завести переменную, содержащую объект *анонимного типа*, только [с использованием `var`](https://ideone.com/B2xC0F) (ну или с помощью трюков с generic'ами).

---

Однако, `var` [*не может*](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/ericlippert/why-no-var-on-fields) быть использовано для инициализаторов полей.

Comment: Спасибо, @vladd, т.е. получается var это не объект, это так называемый псевдоним куска кода, который достроит компилятор. Разобрался.

Comment: @pincher1519: да, это просто заменяет настоящий тип переменной.

Comment: var, в принципе, означает, что даже на этапе компиляции вы не знаете, какой тип будет у переменной. Но этот тип может быть однозначно вычислен компилятором для данного конкретного куска кода. Декларация введена, судя по всему, в качестве синтаксического сахара для работы с шаблонными типами.

Comment: @uilenspiegel: Давайте я переформулирую.

1. Компилятор знает тип переменной на этапе компиляции, т. к. он знает тип выражения в правой части инициализации.
2. Знает ли тип переменной программист, зависит от его умственных способностей и знания стандарта. Он может выяснить для себя тип правой части, и он же будет типом переменной.
3. Декларация с `var` нужна для анонимных типов, а также чтобы избежать бессмысленных повторений кода.

Comment: Программисту не надо знать тип правой части, если он однозначно вычисляется компилятором. Полезно, но не обязательно. С п. 3 согласен, var - синтаксический сахар, избавляющий от написания вручную кучи кода, который, вместо этого, пишет компилятор.

Comment: @uilenspiegel: угу, я не совсем чётко выразился: он _не должен_ выяснять его для себя (хотя и может, если захочет). Иногда можно специально написать `var` для того, чтобы подчеркнуть, что точный тип не важен.

Comment: @uilenspiegel, @vladd, что-то не могу себе представить ситуации для программиста, когда он не должен знать о типе объекта в правой части... Это, на мой взгляд, как сказать, что программист не должен знать о возникающих Exception при вызове того или иного метода.

Comment: @pincher1519 http://csharpindepth.com/ViewNote.aspx?NoteID=61

Comment: > Это, на мой взгляд, как сказать, что программист не должен знать о возникающих Exception при вызове того или иного метода. 

Исключения происходят (если происходят) во время выполнения программы. Вычисление типа переменной, объявленной как var, происходит во время компиляции программы. Т.е. до её первого запуска.

Comment: @pincher1519: я хотел ответить, но статья по ссылке @Котик'а объясняет это лучше меня: абстракции! мы работаем не с `int` и `Person`, мы работаем с `numberOfGirls` и `currentCustomer`, и это гораздо более важно. И не так важно, как именно называется тип этого самого `currentCustomer`.

Comment: @pincher1519 Знать и писать -- разные глаголы. Дело в том, что все эти C, паскали, джавы считаются языками со статической типизацией и *избыточными* объявлениями типа. `var` -- способ просто не писать лишнего.

Answer (score 7):

`var` - это ключевое слово, которое позволяет не указывать тип локальной переменной в случае, когда он может быть получен из правой части выражения.

Использовать следует везде, где тип переменной очевиден из той самой правой части выражения, либо где имя типа очень длинное и сильно загромождает код.

Comment: Возьму в оборот, попробую ещё в качестве локальных классов, может понравится, хотя int i = 0; i++; смотрится приятнее чем var i = 0; i++;

Comment: > int i = 0; i++; смотрится приятнее чем var i = 0; i++;

Это привычка. Со временем пройдет.

Comment: @flammable, кстати, а какой компилятор объект даст в этом случае? Int, int, byte, longint, Int64...

Comment: @pincher1519, int.

Comment: `int`, потому что это тип правой части (константы 0). (`System.Int32` — это то же, что и `int`.)