# Динамический и анонимный тип?

Tags: c#

Возвращаясь к моему вопросу заданному ранее: [Приведение типа к dynamic](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/647771/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BF%D0%B0-%D0%BA-dynamic)
и ответа данного на него, что привидени типов там никакого нет, и что левая часть примит занчеение правой - т.е на строке:

```
dynamic instance = new Program();
```

тип dynamic примет тип Program, то принимая это во внимание и то, что обычно для хранения анононимных типов используется тип `var`

```
var instance = new { Name = "Alex", Age = 27 };
```

Значит, если я использую анонимные и динамические типы в c#, т.е.:

```
dynamic instance = new { Name="Alex", Age = 27 };
```

то `dynamic` примет тип `var` исходя из выше написанного?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вывод сделан неверно.

`var` - это **НЕ** тип (хотя да, в [справке](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us//library/bb383973.aspx) он указывается как *implicit type*). Тип выводится компилятором в момент компиляции.

В случае с анонимными типами: в момент компиляции они получают вполне конкретное имя. Поэтому во время компиляции строка

```
var instance = new { Name = "Alex", Age = 27 };
```

будет заменена на что-то вроде

```
<>f__AnonymousType0`2 instance = new <>f__AnonymousType0`2 { Name = "Alex", Age = 27 };
```

Следовательно и dynamic будет хранить этот созданный тип.

Answer (score 7):

Типа `var` не существует. Это [синтаксический сахар](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/210534/106). В обоих случаях `instance` будет указывать на объект анонимного типа, сгенерированного компилятором.

```
var instance = new { Name = "Alex", Age = 27 };
Console.WriteLine(instance.GetType());

dynamic dynamicInstance = new { Name = "Alex", Age = 27 };
Console.WriteLine(dynamicInstance.GetType());
```

Результат:

> <>f__AnonymousType0`2[System.String,System.Int32]
>
> <>f__AnonymousType0`2[System.String,System.Int32]

Comment: но при этом в справке они его указывают как _implicit **type**_, что вводит в некоторое заблуждение. Либо опять трудности перевода.

Comment: @Grundy согласен. Фраза *"variables have an implicit type `var`"* уводит не в ту сторону. Формулировка из соседнего предложения куда лучше: *"implicitly typed variable"*.

Comment: @Grundy [вот тут](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384061.aspx) уже в кавычках написали, что ближе к истине. Так что это просто проблема документации.

Comment: @Grundy засабмитил [пулл-реквест](https://github.com/dotnet/docs/pull/1980) :). Правда, это касается http://docs.microsoft.com, не уверен, что у них с MSDN один источник.

Comment: Ничоси, как они оперативно ответили :)

Comment: @Grundy это ж бот.

Comment: Забавно :) один уже заапрувил!